# Getting data from core data

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Swift and I am beginning to learn Core Data, but I have a problem. I can't get data from my Core Data database.
I want to download  with Firebase in  core data
For some reason the data displayed from the Firebase and not from the database.
How can I extract data from database?

This my controller :

```
    class InfoProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageProfile: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var nickProfile: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailProfile: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberProfile: UILabel!

    var userData: UserData?

    var managedObjextContext:NSManagedObjectContext!

    var infoProfile = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.userData = UserData(user: (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser)!)
        managedObjextContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        showAllUsers()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

   private func loadData(){
        let presentRequest:NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()

        do {
            infoProfile = try managedObjextContext.fetch(presentRequest)
            print()

        }catch {
            print("Could not load data from database \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private func showAllUsers() {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(UserData.DRIVERS_LOCATION_KEY).observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let userItem = User(context: self.managedObjextContext)

            if self.emailProfile.text != ""{

                userItem.name = (self.userData?.nick)!
                userItem.number = (self.userData?.number)!
                userItem.avataURL = (self.userData?.avatarUrl)!
                userItem.email = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email!

                do {
                    try self.managedObjextContext.save()
                    self.loadData()
                    print("Good save")
                }catch {
                    print("Could not save data \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
       //this my problem    
            do {
                for profil in self.infoProfile{
                    self.emailProfile.text = profil.email
                    print(profil.email as Any)
                    self.nickProfile.text = profil.name
                    self.numberProfile.text = profil.number
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

My model: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase doesn't just populate your Core Data db -- you have to do that yourself.

You may want to look into Firebase's offline capabilities which are more automatic (and do not use CoreData): https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html

Comment: How І can fill the Core Data db ?

Comment: It's not easy to just explain that here -- you should read the CoreData documentation.  Essentially, create entities (like User), set their attributes, save them.  But, you need to know how to initialize the database, contexts, etc.